# Selenium java to call java script function

Tags: java, selenium

After click the clone link. the page will pop out a same windows to ask input the value. then call the java script function.

this is the page source code for onCloneFilter function

```
 function onCloneFilter(name) {
    var new_name=prompt('Please type new filter name:','');
        if (new_name == "") {
        return false;
    }
```

how can I call this function by using java Selenium

Comment: just simulate the action that clicking the clone link....

Comment: you should not call the javascript function in the website directly. If you want to test those javascript, please use unit test. Selenium is focus on the functional test which is a black-box testing. You should assume you know nothing about how the website work(which mean you don't know which js function you are calling)

Answer (score 1):

To run JavaScript in the context of the currently selected frame or window. There is no need to write separate script to execute JavaScript within the browser using Selenium WebDriver script. Just use predefined interface named 'Java Script Executor'

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
            //Uncomment each scenario by using Ctrl + Shift + \ (backslash) and find the solution

            *//to type text in Selenium WebDriver without using sendKeys() method
            js.executeScript("document.getElementById('some id').value='someValue';");
            js.executeScript("document.getElementById('Email').value='SoftwareTestingMaterial.com';");*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JavascriptExecutor class to execute Javascript. Assuming this function is already loaded in html.

```
JavascriptExecutor js=(JavascriptExecutor) driver;
String name=(String) js.executeScript("return onCloneFilter(name)");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use selenium RC API getEval("js code");

```
selenium.getEval("onCloneFilter");
```